# Joomla 2.5: Find installed Joomla version from external application

Tags: php, joomla

I'm hosting quite a lot of Joomla website that I made for my clients.

Because of the large number of websites, it's hard to keep track of all current Joomla versions as I update them whenever I need to make adjustments to one of the websites.

Is there a way to read the current Joomla version from my external PHP application?

I have full access of course via FTP and MySQL if needed.

There is a class called JVersion in `libraries/cms/version/version.php` which has the installed version and build.

Is there a way to readout the `$RELEASE and $DEV_LEVEL;` values outside the Joomla Framework?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Not sure how to read the version yet from my application in a passive way but for now I am using the code below to output the version within Joomla:

```
  jimport('joomla.version');
  $version = new JVersion();
  $joomlaVersion = $version->RELEASE.".".$version->DEV_LEVEL;
```

Comment: It is possible, by importing the Joomla framework in your external application. You might be able to read the update.xml file on the official Joomla site, however I'm not actually sure if this is ethical or allowed

Comment: You could create a really simple module that simply returns that info as a json array or something when you hit a certain url like site.com/my_joomla_version or something like that.

Comment: This may help you http://www.whitefirdesign.com/resources/check-what-version-of-joomla-you-are-running.html

Comment: @JobinJose That's indeed what I am trying to achieve. Need to find out how it's done like that.

Comment: @Cornelis79 it reads the meta generator tag and showing the version details.

Comment: @JobinJose The Meta tag isn't showing the version information unfortunately so not entirely sure how they manage the read out the version.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Currently following your idea to output the version number manually that I then can pick up with my own application via curl or something.